# Discord JDA - Invalid Member List

Tags: java, bots, discord, discord-jda

I am creating a Discord bot and have encountered a strange problem. I need to go through each user on the server and perform a conditional action. But when receiving a list of all Members, it contains only me and the bot itself.

```
public class Bot extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent Event) {
        String Message = Event.getMessage().getContentRaw();

        if(Message.charAt(0) == Globals.BOT_PREFIX) {
            String[] Args = Message.split("\\s+");

        if(Args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(CommandType.COMMAND_DEV_TEST)) {
            List<Member> MemberList = Event.getGuild().getMembers();
            for(int i = 0; i < MemberList.size(); i++)
                System.out.println(MemberList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

If another person writes, then only me and the bot are still displayed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume you're using a development version of the 4.2.0 release (4.1.1_102 and above)

In these versions, the new factory methods have been introduced to make people aware of the new discord API design. In the future, bots will be limited to cache members who connected to voice channels by default.

**If all you need is the count of members you can just use [Guild#getMemberCount](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#getMemberCount())! Otherwise:**

The `createDefault`/`createLight` will only cache members connected to voice channels or owners of guilds (on first sight). To cache more members, you will have to enable the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent in both the application dashboard for your bot and in JDA.

[image]

Now you can do something like this:

```java
JDA api = JDABuilder.createDefault(token)
                    .setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.ALL)
                    .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
                    .build();
```

The `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent is needed because it enables the `GUILD_MEMBER_REMOVE` dispatch to tell the library to remove a member from the cache when they are kicked/banned/leave.

This setup will perform **lazy loading**, which means it will start with only voice members and add more members to the cache once they become active.

To load all members on startup you have to additionally enable **member chunking**:

```java
JDABuilder.createDefault(token)
          .setChunkingFilter(ChunkingFilter.ALL) // enable member chunking for all guilds
          .setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.ALL)
          .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
          .build();
```

You can also load them for individual guilds using [Guild#loadMembers](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#loadMembers()) or [Guild#findMembers](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#findMembers(java.util.function.Predicate)).

I recommend to also read this JDA wiki article: [Gateway Intents and Member Cache Policy](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/Gateway-Intents-and-Member-Cache-Policy).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what was needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: How does loadMembers work? From the documentation, it seems like it will be useful for the feature that I am trying to implement, but I am not very proficient in java, so I don't know how the Task works. Is it like a promise a something? How can I get the final lists of members once the task ends processing?

Comment: @OctavianT. If still relevant: You can use the [Task](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/utils/concurrent/Task.html) in several ways. Synchronously get the execution result through a method `get()` or asynchronously execute code with the result of a task through a method `onSuccess(result -> ...)` using lamba function for example. Very similar to Promise from JS. For example: `response.json().then(json => ...)`