# Java Discord Bot - Get Members of a role?

Tags: java, bots, discord, discord-jda

I am currently working on a java discord bot (net.dv8tion) and I try to create a "who" command, that should list you the people of the picked role, for example: !who admin  --> list of all people with the "admin" role. So my problem is, that I couldn't actually find a method or any other way to solve this problem.
I hope that some of you might help me with this problem ^^

I thought about something like this, or similar:

```
list <> members = guild.getMembersByRole(roleName);
```

or:

```
role rolename;
String[] members = rolename.getMembers();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with 2 steps:

1. Get the target role
2. Get the members of that role

To get the role you can either use [`getRolesByName`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#getRolesByName(java.lang.String,boolean)) or [`getRoleById`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#getRoleById(long)).

For example:

```java
List<Role> roles = guild.getRolesByName("admin", true);
Role role = guild.getRoleById(698231912904523796L);
```

Once you have the role(s) you can use [`getMembersWithRoles`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#getMembersWithRoles(java.util.Collection)).

```java
List<Member> members = guild.getMembersWithRoles(roles);
```

If the resulting list of members is empty or missing members despite the roles being correct, it is possible that the members are not cached. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61229594/10630900) for further details on that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick help, it's working perfectly ^^