# Discord API not able to retrieve correct amount of members in Guild

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I've tried to retrieve all users in a Guild or a channel. I've tried different ways but without any desired result.

Method #1.

```java
public static List<Member> getMembers() {
    return Arrays.stream(WebClient.builder().build()
        .get()
        .uri(URL)
        .header("Authorization", "Bot " + Credentials.TOKEN)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Member[].class)
        .block()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This only retrieves the last user that joined the server.

Method #2

```java
Guild guild = event.getJDA().getGuildById(GUILD_ID);

event.getChannel().sendMessage("Users: " + guild.getMembers().size()).queue();
```

This retrieves only 2 users. While debugging I found that it's retrieving the bot itself and me.

Method #3

```java
public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
    String messageSent = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();
    
    if (messageSent.equalsIgnoreCase("members")) {
        Guild guild = event.getJDA().getGuildById(GUILD_ID);

        event.getChannel().sendMessage("Users: " +
            guild.getMembers().size()).queue();            
    
        event.getChannel().sendMessage("Thats all for now").queue();
    }
}
```

Same as #2.

Method #4

```java
public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
    String messageSent = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();
        
    event.getChannel().getMembers().forEach(member -> {
        event.getChannel().sendMessage("[Channel - " + event.getChannel().getName() + " ]").queue();
        
        event.getChannel().sendMessage("---- Members -> " + member.getUser().getName()).queue();
    });
}
```

Same as #2 and #3

When debugging I found that like #2 in #3 and #4 it only retrieves the bot and me.

Sometimes if another users executes the command, the bot retrieves that user and the bot itself.

> According to the documentation GuildChannel.getMembers() returns all
> Members with the {@link net.dv8tion.jda.api.Permission#MESSAGE_READ}
> Permission

So, I have give all users the permission to read messages in my test server.

> The documentation also says that Guild.getMembers() will only check
> cached members!

What am I doing wrong?
What should I do to be able to get all the users in a Guild or a channel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Minn your answer solved my issue :) Won't my bot by banned for retrieving a lot of users or because I'm using ChunkingFilter.ALL, MemberCachePolicy.ALL, GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: It will not be banned but it will [limit your bot to 100 servers unless it is verified](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040720412) and you need to explicitely enable the intent in the developer portal.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

```
event.getJDA().getGuildById(GUILD_ID).getMemberCount();
```

---

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61229594/10871900), you could enable the privileged server members endpoint and cache all members. Your bot can not join more than 100 servers without being verified then, however.

This amount is exact but caching all members in all guilds will also use up much RAM.

A way better solution is to use the count from [the guild endpoint](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild). You can send a GET request to `/guilds/<id>?with_counts=true` and use `approximate_member_count`.

JDA even uses this endpoint.
`Guild` has a method [`getMemberCount`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.dv8tion/JDA/4.2.0_203/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#getMemberCount()) that gives you the (approximate) number of members in this guild.

Comment: Thanks. In case I need to access each member, probably /guilds/<id>?with_counts=true would be useless for me, right? Kinda sad that I did not saw anywhere in the docs that I need to enable privilegied server members endpoint.

Comment: Yes but if you need to access a specific member snd know the id, you can use `retrieveMemberById`. That does not even require the privileged intent.