# JDA getMembers() only returns users who wrote in the chat since the bot's startup?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm currently developing my discord bot in Java with the JDA. It worked well until two weeks ago. Since this time the JDA seems no longer capable of getting all users via the event.getGuild().getMembers(), it will only return members who wrote in the chat since the bot has started. With the event.getGuild().getMemberCount() method the JDA will provide the correct amount of users, but if I check the length of the list with event.getGuild().getMembers().length it will only give the amount of users, which wrote in the chat before. What did I do wrong?

My Code which should get a list of all members:

```
        String msg = "`" + guild.getMembers().get(0).getUser().getAsTag() + "`";
        List<Member> members = guild.getMembers();


        for (int i = 1; i < guild.getMemberCount(); i++) {
            msg = msg + ", `" + members.get(i).get.getUser().getAsTag() + "`" + event.getGuild().getMemberCount();
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord JDA - Invalid Member List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226721/discord-jda-invalid-member-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're using only returns the cached members, to get all the members you'll need to use `Guild#loadMembers()`.

Read more about that here: https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#loadMembers()