# JDA guild.getMembers() no longer getting all members, since few days ago

Tags: java, discord

This is my code that Ive used for a long time, since before the recent JDA changes in I think July

```
for (Member member : guild.getMembers()) {
 // code
}
```

This no longer works, and it only cycles through about 4 members before stopping. Is there anything new I need to add to this since the patch? I commented out the entire loop body and just put a system.println member.getEffectiveName() and it just prints 4 names every time, when there are about 80 people in the discord.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord JDA - Invalid Member List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226721/discord-jda-invalid-member-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to cache members to loop through them.
When using methods such as `getMember()` or `getMemberById()` unless its the owner of guild or the bot itself its null.

When using `createLight()` or `createDefault()` for building a JDA Member Caching and Member Chunking is disabled by default.

Things like User class can't be null, as it is provided by discord

For more info on caching all members read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226721/discord-jda-invalid-member-list)

Comment: perfect. Thank you very much :)