# Bot can't see anyone in channel/guild besides itself and me

Tags: java, discord-jda

Java/JDA beginner here.

As stated in the headline, my discord bot is unable to see anyone besides itself and me in a given channel/guild. In order to see this, I use the following code:

```
// members in channel
List<Member> members = c.getMembers();
String numOfMembers = String.valueOf(members.size());
c.sendMessage("I see "+numOfMembers+" members in this channel:").queue();
for (int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++) {
        String member = members.get(i).getEffectiveName();
        c.sendMessage(member).queue();
}

// members in guild (server)
members = g.getMembers();
numOfMembers = String.valueOf(members.size());
c.sendMessage("I see "+numOfMembers+" members in this server:").queue();
for (int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++) {
        String member = members.get(i).getEffectiveName();
        c.sendMessage(member).queue();
}
```

I've heard this is because of missing intents, which I then implemented like this (and yes, I enabled the privileged intents in the application panel):

```
JDABuilder builder = JDABuilder.createDefault("TOKEN");
//EnumSet.allOf(GatewayIntent.class)
builder.addEventListeners(new MessageReceiveListener());
builder.enableIntents(
        GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS,
        GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
);
MemberCachePolicy policy = MemberCachePolicy.ALL;
builder.setMemberCachePolicy(policy);
jda = builder.build();
```

Just in case, I tried setting the member cache policy to all, but neither of these approaches fixed the problem. Did I implement the Intents wrong, or is there something I'm missing?

Also, the bot *is able* to tag a user other than itself/me if it's responding to their message. Not sure if this is relevant, but thought I'd add it in if it is.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Found the solution here: [Discord JDA - Invalid Member List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226721/discord-jda-invalid-member-list)

Basically, my code was missing a chunking filter, meaning the bot would only recognize members that are/have been active. The filter can be implemented like this: `builder.setChunkingFilter(ChunkingFilter.ALL);`