# Java JDA GatewayIntents member caching is not caching members. What could I be doing wrong?

Tags: java, discord

I am trying to make my bot return all members of the server when I run a specific command but it only returns the bot.

```
JDA jda = JDABuilder.createLight(token, GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES, GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS, GatewayIntent.GUILD_PRESENCES)
            .addEventListeners(new Commands())
            .setActivity(Activity.playing("slopping innocent people (i hate them)"))
            .setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE)
            .build();
```

this is what I have to create the GatewayIntents

```
List<Member> memberList = event.getGuild().getMembers();
    for(int i = 0; i < memberList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(memberList.get(i));
    }
```

and this is just a simple code snippet of how I want to test the list. But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord JDA - Invalid Member List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226721/discord-jda-invalid-member-list)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a development version of the 4.2.0 release or latest releases

In the newer versions, bots will be limited to cache members who connected to voice channels by default.

If all you need is the count of members you can just use Guild#getMemberCount